# Reload Android OS on Moto G Peregrine

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, clockworkmod-recovery

After running into some issues with Cyanogenmod, I want to reload the default Android OS for my Moto G Peregrine. Here's what I've managed to synthesize from various forum posts on the Internet.

1. Get the OS file from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/4g-development/xt1039-moto-g-4g-stock-firmware-kxb21-t2805619).
2. Flash the image using `Clockworkmod` using the same instructions as loading Cyanogenmod, that can be found [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_peregrine#Installing_CyanogenMod_from_recovery).

Is this the correct procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the correct procedure. After you get the firmware you need to unzip it and from that folder run the following commands, assuming that you're on Linux:

```
sudo fastboot flash partition gpt.bin
sudo fastboot flash motoboot motoboot.img
sudo fastboot flash logo logo.bin
sudo fastboot flash boot boot.img
sudo fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
sudo fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0
sudo fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1
sudo fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2
sudo fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3
sudo fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin
sudo fastboot erase modemst1 
sudo fastboot erase modemst2 
sudo fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn
sudo fastboot erase cache 
sudo fastboot erase userdata 
sudo fastboot reboot
```

I needed the `sudo` because I messed up the permissions on my USB, so maybe you won't need it. Also, I think the windows equivalent to `fastboot` is `mfastboot`.